# vba: iterating through a range and updating another range one cell at a time

Tags: vba, range

All,

In Sheet 1, column A I have the following list of n number

```
12
250
1600
100
2000
:
:
34
```

I have a look up table which can be embedded in the code

```
Min Max Grade
0   100  A
100 200  B
300 500  C
:
:
1000 2000 H
2000 5000 L
5000+     M
```

In Sheet 2, column A, I want n Grades corresponding to the numbers in sheet 1 to appear, based on the look up table. I would like to do it using VBA only and not excel formulas. How can I do it? thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is the lookup table?

Comment: It can be embedded within VBA code as 'if then else' or 'select case' logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim strGrade As String

    lRow = 1

    ws1.Activate
    'Loop through the rows getting the letter grade for the score.
    Do While lRow <= ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Get the score
        If ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value = "" Then
            score = -1
        Else
            score = ws1.Range("A" & lRow).Value
        End If

        'Get the grade for the score
        Select Case score
        Case 0 To 100
            strGrade = "A"
        Case 100 To 200
            strGrade = "B"
        Case 300 To 500
            strGrade = "C"
        Case 1000 To 2000
            strGrade = "H"
        Case 2000 To 5000
            strGrade = "L"
        Case Is > 5000
            strGrade = "M"
        Case Else
            strGrade = "?"
        End Select

        'Write the grade to sheet 2
        ws2.Range("A" & lRow).Value = strGrade

        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```